# Change order increment_id of existing orders

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders, increment-id

In a test system I would like to change increment_id for all orders. Otherwise I would get conflics with another module.

Can I simple change increment_id in sales_flat_order or will this messup Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320412/956397) it should be fine to change `sales_flat_order`.

I run two querys to change order id:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET increment_id = CONCAT('10-', increment_id);
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET increment_id = CONCAT('10-', increment_id);
```

And no problems so far.

**Update**

As mentioned by [R.S.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40737/change-order-increment-id-of-existing-orders#comment55784_40740) you may also like to change the next order id prefix.

Here is some **untested** code for this:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='10-'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Also you might need to change `increment_last_id` in `eav_entity_store` but I am not sure. I did not need this.

Comment: You may also need to change your "Order Prefix" so that the next order will follow the above logic

Comment: @R.S good point! I did not but I added it to the answer in case someelse does.

Comment: Also as a further note of caution the above will not work if you have prefixed your Magento database tables and should only ever be executed after a database backup and really only if you are absolutely certain on what you are doing.